# tabllespce error in DB2 reorg statement

Tags: sql, database, db2

I applied an ALTER command to one of my tables namely CERTIFICATE
After which I had to reorg the table as I wasn't able to perform any  select, Insert statements. 
I used the following query to execute from SQL,

```
call sysproc.admin_cmd('reorg table CERTIFICATE');


Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-2217, SQLSTATE=01H52, SQLERRMC=1, DRIVER=3.50.152
SQLState:  01H52
ErrorCode: -2217
```

The error 2217 shows that the available system tablespace is smaller than the page size of the table data. 
Is there any way to get through this problem using SQL commands.?

Comment: You need to create a system temporary tablespace using CREATE TABLESPACE with a page size that matches that one for your table CERTIFICATE.

Comment: refer this [link](http://www.dbatodba.com/db2/how-to-do/how-to-increase-a-tablespace/view) to increase the table space

Comment: Hi @data_henrik, could anyone plz tell, whether we can create table spaces from SQL whithout using command line environment? If yes how?

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000929.html has the syntax for CREATE TABLESPACE. It is a regular SQL command. You need the proper privileges as it deals with resources for the entire database.

Comment: if you add details about what page size is required, someone might compose the needed SQL statement for you. What version of DB2 are you on? Which OS?

Comment: I am using DB2  9.7 , OS is Windows 7. I am a new to DB2, and have come to know about all this only via GOOGLE. How could I possibly find the page  size required?